# Retrieve row where control added to a TableLayoutPanel was placed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have an operation that adds controls to a `TableLayoutPanel`, and I want to set each new row's `SizeType` to `AutoSize`.

The code below doesn't work because it doesn't retrieve the actual row number, the result of `.GetRow(e.Control)` gets to be `-1`. Which event should I handle to get the correct index?

```
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(sender As Object, e As ControlEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.ControlAdded
    Dim i = TableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(e.Control) 'i = -1 ... why?
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(i).SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read/intuit the documentation very carefully.

From [TableLayoutPanel.GetRow Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getrow(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The row position of control, or -1 if the position of control is determined by LayoutEngine.

The **LayoutEngine** part of that statement is the key.  You need a method that to return the position determined by it.  Luckily you have the [TableLayoutPanel.GetPositionFromControl Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getpositionfromcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The GetPositionFromControl method returns the actual current position of control, even if its position is determined by the LayoutEngine.

You can continue to use the ControlAdded event.

```
Dim i As Int32 = TableLayoutPanel1.GetPositionFromControl(e.Control).Row
```